# solving inequality contains logarithm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, logarithms

I have the following inequality:

$$0.39n\log(n) \leq S \leq 0.5n\log(n)$$

How can I find a proper range for $n$?

I can have something like: $$10^{S/0.5} \leq n^n \leq 10^{S/0.39}$$

But it's not merely based on $n$, also it'll produces a large number for most of the numbers and will cause overflow in computer's memory.

Comment: Do you know $S$? If you know $S$ then you will have to do is by numerical evaluation of $n\log n$ (if $n\in \mathbb{N}$ it should be pretty easy) or use Lambert's $W$ function.

Comment: Yes $S$ is a number and n∈N.

Comment: So if you know $S$ then write a loop which is looping through $n$ and check when $0.39n\log n > S$. The upper bound on the left side is $n_0 = S/0.39$. Similarly, you can do the same procedure with the right-hand side of the inequality. Btw +1 for good question and Euler avatar :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath You mean I can use a variable like $t$ instead of $nlog(n)$ then solve $10^i = n^n$ where $i$ is a number from $S/0.5$ to $S/0.39$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MrYouMath commented, using [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) could be a good way to avoid loops.

The solution of $a n \log(n)=S$ is given by
$$n=\frac{\left(\frac Sa\right)}{ W\left(\frac{S}{a}\right)}$$
Assuming that $S$ is a large number, the Wikipedia page gives approximations for large values of the argument

$$W(x)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(6-9L_2+2L_2^2)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(x)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

Comment: This seems more like an overcomplicating than finding a range for $n$. Can you please tell me how this will give me a proper range of numbers for $n$?

Comment: Jus apply the formula for $x=\frac Sa$ with $a=0.39$ and then $a=0.50$. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the $S$ that you are looking for. The inequality that you want to solve is

$$n\log n \leq \frac{S}{0.39} $$

and

$$\frac {S}{0.50} \leq n\log n .$$

It is easy to evaluate $n\log n$

Determine $1\log 1,2\log 2, \ldots, k\log k$, if $k\log k$ is the first number to surpass $S/0.39$ then $n<k$. For the right-hand side. Use the same method for the second inequality. Note that you can use the previous results and continue until $K\log K$ which is the first number which is larger than $S/0.50$ then $n\geq K$.

If you want to find the limit's depending on $S$ then you will have to use the method described by Claude Leibovici.